# Is it possible to perform a custom operation on all elements of an MPI_Datatype?

Tags: c++, mpi

I am a beginner at using MPI for multi-CPU parallel programming.

In my task, I create a new user `MPI_Dataype` using [`MPI_Type_create_subarray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/message-passing-interface/mpi-type-create-subarray-function) from a much larger 2D array. Using it in MPI communication is straightforward, but I need to update the values of this subarray first. For now, this is done using two `for` loops over the original array, but I would like to merge the subarray definition for computation and communication.

**Is it possible to extract an array of pointers from a user defined MPI datatype** that I could iterate over? The ideal end-goal here would be creating a function that would update only some elements of the large array by taking an `MPI_Dataype` as an argument. This doesn't seem to be the usual use-case (for obvious reasons) and I couldn't find any advice on how to do it.

Alternatively, am I better off just dropping this idea and staying with my current approach?

Comment: have a look at `MPI_Type_get_envelope()` to figure out how `MPI_Type_create_subarray()` was invoked, and then you can build your arrays of pointers or get the loop start/end indexes.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet This looks like exactly the thing I need, thank you for the hint! I assume this is similar to what `MPI_Send()` would be also doing in the background? I tried looking into the Open MPI Send [source code](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/master/ompi/mpi/c/send.c), but it wasn't exactly easy to read with the amounts of macros.

Comment: Open MPI internally uses optimized description and conversion. If you want an efficient and Open MPI only solution, start from `ompi/mpi/c/pack.c` to see how a datatype is packed. you would basically perform your operation instead of `memcpy()`.